# Removing custom claims

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, firebase-admin

I am developing a project which uses custom claims to make users admins.
My client wants to be able to remove users admin privileges but I am struggling to be able to remove them. Currently I have this code for my functions:

```
// Remove token

exports.removeToken = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  return admin.auth().getUserByEmail(data.email).then(user => {
    return admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(user.uid,{
      claim: null
    })
  }).then(()=> {
    return {
      message: `Success! ${data.email} has been removed as an admin.`
    }
  }).catch (err => {
    return err;
  });
});
```

and for the component itself the code is this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
const firebase = require("firebase");

export default class RemoveAdmin extends Component {

    state = {
        removeAdminEmail: '',
        results: ''
    }

    updateEmail = (e) => {
        this.setState({
            removeAdminEmail: e.target.value
        })
    }

    updateUserStatus = (Email) => {
        firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(Email).update({
          accountStatus: "User"
        })
      }
    

    removeAdmin = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const removeAdminRole = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('removeToken');
        removeAdminRole({email: this.state.removeAdminEmail}).then(this.setState({ results: "This user is no longer an admin"}))
        this.updateUserStatus(this.state.removeAdminEmail)
    }

    render() {
        const result = this.state.results ? <div className = "ResultsBox">{this.state.results}</div> : ''
        return (
            <div className = "AddAdminForm">
            <form className = "admin-actions" onSubmit={this.removeAdmin}>
                <p> Remove Admin </p>
                <input type = "email" placeholder = "Enter users email address" id = "admin-email"  onChange={this.updateEmail} required/>
                <button type="submit"> Make Admin </button>
                {result}
                
            </form>
        </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Basically, the admin enters the email address of the user they want to remove the privileges of, it then gives them a custom claim and changes the "accountStatus" field in the database back to user.

I am getting the following error message

```
Unhandled Rejection (Error): internal
```

which isn't giving me much info!

Comment: What do you get if you log the error: `.catch (err => { console.log(err);return err;});`?

Comment: Actually, doing `setCustomUserClaims(userID, {claim: null})` **does not generate any error** if `userID` is a correct user ID. You probably have a problem with the email. Can you check its value, in addition to logging the error as proposed above.

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Thanks for the help! 
I am currently getting this error in my console 

```
Access to fetch at '**LINK TO FUNCTION**' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.
```

Comment: You should either try to deploy both the Cloud Function and the app, or use the Emulator and connect your app to the emulator. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/connect_functions

Comment: @RenaudTarnec This worked! I am not sure if that was the problem or whether it was because I was accidently deploying to a different version of the project >.< either way, it works now so thank you!

Answer (score 1):

To remove all the Custom Claims assigned to a user, you need to pass an empty object, as follows:

```
return admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(user.uid, {});
```

To remove only one of the Custom Claims assigned to a user, you need to pass an object containing all the current Custom Claims **but the one you want to delete**, as follows:

```
// set two claims
return admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(user.uid, {admin: true, writer: true});

// remove the Admin claim
return admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(user.uid, {writer: true});
```

Answer (score 1):

`setCustomUserClaims` always overrides the existing custom claims of the provided user. It receives the uid as first argument and an object with the user claims OR `null` as a second.

The solution to your error is most likely calling `setCustomUserClaims(user.uid, null)` instead of `setCustomUserClaims(user.uid, { claim: null })`. Note that this will override all existing claims of the user.

If you want to retain other claims on the user, get the claims first and then call `setCustomUserClaims` with the updated custom claims object.

```js
const { customClaims: oldCustomClaims } = await admin.auth().getUser(user.uid)

const updatedCustomClaims = oldCustomClaims

delete updatedCustomClaims.admin

admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(user.uid, updatedCustomClaims)
```

See: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.Auth-1#setcustomuserclaims

---

**Getting a more helpful error message from firebase cloud functions**

Instead of simply returning the error as you do in your cloud function, use the `HttpsError` constructor instead.

```js
return new HttpsError("internal", error.message);
```

This will pass the error along with the error message to the client properly.